# AKKA Futures and Java Threads

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have a question on the usage of Futures in one of the questions asked - [Are Futures executed on a single thread? (Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778254/are-futures-executed-on-a-single-thread-scala) . If for reach Future a new/independent thread is used, then what advantage does AKKA offer than Java threads? The number of WebClients are limited by the max number of thread that the application can spawn right? And the number of threads will be very less compared to number of actors that the system can create. I just wanted to know if there are any other approaches so that when huge number of requests come in, the system will be able to handle them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Futures` are executed using an `ExecutionContext`. There are multiple ways to construct an `ExecutionContext`. One of them is to create it using an `ExecutionService`. The `ExecutionService` can be a `ForkJoinPool` or a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, for example. Depending on the implementation of the `ExecutionService`, your futures will be executed spawning a new `Thread` or reusing existing ones.